How to resolve TypeScript error when using generic return types with Sequelize Models
I'm working with sequelize-typescript and trying to create a generic function that returns specific model instances based on the provided model class. My setup looks like this:
import { Model, ModelCtor } from 'sequelize-typescript';

export type ModelClass<M extends BaseModel> = ModelCtor<M> & typeof BaseModel;

class BaseModel extends Model {}
class Plane extends BaseModel {
    wingType: string;
}
class Car extends BaseModel {
    wheelType: string;
}
class Boat extends BaseModel {
    rudderType: string;
}

type ModelClasses = {
    Car: Car;
    Plane: Plane;
    Boat: Boat;
};

async function returnModel<M extends keyof ModelClasses>(ModelClass: ModelClass<ModelClasses[M]>): Promise<ModelClasses[M]> {
    const result = await ModelClass.findByPk('123');

    if (!result) {
        throw new Error('Resource not found');
    }

    return result;
}

This code gives me the following Typescript error:
Type 'BaseModel' is not assignable to type 'ModelClasses[M]'.
  Type 'Model<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Car & Plane & Boat'.
    Property 'wheelType' is missing in type 'Model<any, any>' but required in type 'Car'.ts(2322)

It seems like the resulting type is being inferred as Car & Plane & Boat instead of Car | Plane | Boat, which is not what I want.
How can I adjust my code so that TypeScript recognizes the correct return type as one of the specific model classes (e.g., Car | Plane | Boat) instead of trying to combine all of them?
